# Tensorflow object detection : Using transfer learning on local running

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow, transfer-learning

From Tensorflow docs, we can use transfer learning for object detection when you run from [cloud](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/running_pets.md). Also, can we using transfer-learning for running locally ? i see that we have a doc about running on [local](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md) but i can not find any documents that write about transfer learning when run on local machine . I expected it in [pipeline](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/configuring_jobs.md) but i can not find it. So how can we config transfer learning on running locally ?

Comment: If you have of the graph loaded into tensorflow, all you need to do is recreate it, but change the `tf.Varaible`s from the layers you'd like to fix into `tf.Constants`.  If you then re-train the network, only the `tf.Varaible`s will participate in the optimization.

Comment: From [this doc](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/running_pets.md#downloading-a-coco-pretrained-model-for-transfer-learning) I can not understand why they push previous model to `GCS bucket` and how they help us to do transfer learning .

Comment: I don't use google cloud. so what is GCS and why they push it to GCS ?